# trying to get simplest possible example of performSelector: withObject working

Tags: objective-c

Here's my method signature for "targetMethod":

```
-(void)targetMethod: (id)arg;
```

This works:

```
[myObject targetMethod:@"called the regular way"];
```

This doesn't

```
[myObject performSelector:@selector(targetMethod) withObject:@"called using selector"];
```

It results in  the following error:

-[SelectorTest targetMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e075d0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are spelling the selector name wrong.

It's `@selector(targetMethod:)`, not `@selector(targetMethod)`.

The ":" counts; it's part of the method name.

Comment: ack. Of course. Darn. I _wasn't_ spelling it wrong in my more complicated example that wasn't working.

Comment: Thankyou thankyou thankyou! Now I need to go bandage my forehead.

Comment: Doh !  I had the same error, caused by that missing colon.  Thanks!